# Filling empty values in boolean column in Pyspark

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, null

I have a dataframe that has some boolean columns and these columns appear empty sometimes, just like other columns of other data types do.

I need to convert this dataframe to a RDD in which each row is turned into a JSON. For that i use the code below

```
df.toJson().zipWithIndex()
```

However, when a row is null for certain column, the column doesn't get converted to a key, which leaves me with mismatch schema.

I have tried `df.na.fill('').toJson.zipWithIndex()` which deals with the columns that are strings, but it the problem still remains when a column is of int or boolean type.

How can I keep all the columns as keys in the json, even when the value is null?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it, but leaving this here for anyone that might need it.

If you set this property `("spark.sql.jsonGenerator.ignoreNullFields", "false")` when setting your spark Session, spark takes into account null values when generating Json objects.